# What does `brew man` do?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I mean `brew man`, not `man brew`.

It says:

> Fetching: hpricot-0.8.6.gem (100%) Building native extensions.  This
>   could take a while... Successfully installed hpricot-0.8.6 Fetching:
>   rdiscount-2.1.8.gem (100%) Building native extensions.  This could
>   take a while... Successfully installed rdiscount-2.1.8 Fetching:
>   mustache-1.0.1.gem (100%) Successfully installed mustache-1.0.1
>   Fetching: ronn-0.7.3.gem (100%) Successfully installed ronn-0.7.3 4
>   gems installed Writing manpages to /usr/local/share/man/man1

So what have I installed? What does it do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Homebrew issue #40735, [what would the command "brew man cask" do?](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40735) (which can be found by simply googling `"brew man"`)

> `brew man` generates the Homebrew manpage from markdown, using these gems to do the translation.

Comment: What does "Homebrew manpage" mean? Contents of man brew or all the man pages of all the brew packages? Also, what's markdown?

Comment: @seeker_of_bacon Please do some research on your own and only post questions here which cannot be answered by simply googling (as your second question)